# Laplacian filter

Tags: java, image-processing, edge-detection

I have been trying to apply laplacian filter in java.

```
int  red = 8 * red - imageOne.getRed(i - 1, j - 1)
                    - imageOne.getRed(i, j - 1)
                    - imageOne.getRed(i + 1, j - 1)
                    - imageOne.getRed(i - 1, j) - imageOne.getRed(i, j)
                    - imageOne.getRed(i + 1, j)
                    - imageOne.getRed(i - 1, j + 1)
                    - imageOne.getRed(i, j + 1)
                    - imageOne.getRed(i + 1, j + 1);
```

green and blue values are calculated in the same way.

After calculating RGB values, there are some very large values or negative values.
the range being [- 255*8 ... 255*8]

I tried to scale it using

```
     red = (int) (red / 16) + 128;
 green = (int) (green / 16) + 128;
 blue = (int) (blue / 16) + 128;
```

I also have tried restrcting it between [0 - 255] with following code

```
        red = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, red));
```

but the image is still not displayed properly.

How do i handle the RGB values properly ???

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449596/implement-laplacian-3x3?rq=1 might help

Comment: hello RC.. the question you directed me uses the same scaling thing as I did... I changed my scaling thing to the provided one and I am still getting the same picutre..

Comment: Your scaling should be `red = (red + 8 * 255) / 16`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Roger and RC, got it now.. it was a stupid mistake.. i was multiplying wrong pixel...
btw, what's the difference between 
  red = (red + 8 * 255) / 16;
& 
   red = (int) (red / 16) + 128;

Because they both are giving the same value as far as I tested :O

Thanks

Comment: Try `red = -2040` and you get `0` with the correct scaling and `0.5` with your scaling - they are not the same, possibly due to some integer arithmetic.